# Shell Script - Filtering text files by column that will & will not exist

Tags: shell, unix

I want to filter a directory that is full of log files according to the 8th column according to user's input (eg: 1218738496) and output to a text file. I have a working solution, but l am looking for a better solution that offers better performance, as the total file size may exceed 1GB+.

Problem 1:
Format inconsistencies in some lines.

Problem 2:
If the line's 8th column matches the input, the lines below it (that do not contain INSERT) should be output to file as well.

Sample data

```
ACTION,INSTALLATION_ID,LOG_TIMESTAMP_SECONDS,LOG_TIMESTAMP_FRACTIONS,LOG_TIMESTAMP,THREAD_ID,SEQUENCE_NUMBER,LOG_LEVEL_TYPE
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1127192896,0,DEBUG3
0010: 69 6c 65 40 10 92 0f 0e 67 b9 72 aa 5d e1 03 63
]",,default,false
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:13.305 (Asia/Colombo),1127192896,1,DEBUG1
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,14,DEBUG3
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme""><o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold"">
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,15,DEBUG3
0010: 69 6c 65 40 10 92 0f 0e 67 b9 72 aa 5d e1 03 63
]",,default,false
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,17,DEBUG3
```

Desired output

```
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,14,DEBUG3
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme""><o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold"">
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,15,DEBUG3
0010: 69 6c 65 40 10 92 0f 0e 67 b9 72 aa 5d e1 03 63
]",,default,false
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,17,DEBUG3
```

My current working script

```
for file in $(ls -rt $directory)
do
    echo "Reading file : " $file
     # || [[ -n "$line" ]] <-- prevent last line being ignored if doesn't end with newline
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
    do 
        # if line contains INSERT
        if [[ $line == *"INSERT"* ]]
        then
            # Break it to access the thread ID
            breakdown=(${line//,/ })
            threadID=${breakdown[4]}

            if [[ $threadID == "$inputThreadID" ]]
            then
                seqID=${breakdown[5]}
                echo $line >> ./output_unsorted.txt
            fi
        else
            # The "too long lines" check if they belong to the ID log we want
            if [ "$threadID" == "$inputThreadID" ] && [[ $line != *"ACTION,INSTALLATION_ID"* ]]
            then
                if [ "$lastSeqID" != "$seqID" ]
                then
                    echo $line >> ./output_unsorted.txt
                else
                    echo $line >> ./output_unsorted.txt
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done < "$directory/$file"
done
```

Comment: Would anything keep you from doing this in Perl? Seems to me like a better fit than bash.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only do this is bash :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using awk

This produces the output that you ask for:

```
$ awk -F, '/INSERT/{f=0} $4==1218738496{f=1} f' file
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,14,DEBUG3
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme""><o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold"">
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,15,DEBUG3
0010: 69 6c 65 40 10 92 0f 0e 67 b9 72 aa 5d e1 03 63
]",,default,false
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,2015/06/02 14:07:26.860 (Asia/Colombo),1218738496,17,DEBUG3
```

How it works:

- `-F,`

  Set the input field separator to a comma.
- `/INSERT/{f=0}`

  If the line contains `INSERT`, we set flag `f` to zero (false).
- `$4==1218738496{f=1}`

  If the fourth field is your selected number, then we set the flag `f` to one (true).
- `f`

  If `f` is true, print the line.

### Using bash

This uses very similar logic and produces the same output but uses bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=
while IFS= read line
do
    [[ $line == *"INSERT"* ]] && f=
    IFS=, read a b c d rest <<<"$line"
    [ "$d" = 1218738496 ] && f=1
    [ "$f" ] && echo "$line"
done <file
```

Comment: Hi, any idea why this won't work? The output.txt is blank. 

`for file in $(ls -rt $2)
 
do
    
 awk -F, '/INSERT/{f=0} $4==1218738496{f=1} f' "$2$file" >      
./output.txt
    
 done`

Comment: There are a couple issues there.  For that to work, `$2` better end with a `/`.  Also, for every file found, all previously output will be lost because `./output.txt` is overwritten from scratch each time.  (If you want it appended to, instead, then replace `>` with `>>`.)  Also, if any file or directory names contains spaces, that code will not work.

Comment: Thanks , it works like a charm once I have replaced > with >>